# Is there any ways to route ESXi vSwitch via another vSwitch?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, vswitch

Due to specific terms of service provider I need a solution for the following problem.

I have two hosts with a LAN port group for the VM's. Hosts are connected to each other with RPN network. I can't attach images, so here is the [link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0T1O.png). RPN network is **routable**. The first host IP is 10.1.1.1/24 and the second is 10.2.2.2/24. Also RPN network is using for vMotion and iSCSI.

I need to bridge LAN port group between the hosts: VM's placed at LAN group on one host must to see VM's placed at LAN group on other host with the same network (192.168.1.0/24).

The problem is: due to MAC binding of vSwitch2 and network adapters (vmnic1) of RPN network, I can't add additional port group into vSwitch2, if there will be any additional MAC address service provider will down the physical link. Additional IP's for the RPN network also can't be ordered.

So is there any solution to make LAN port group of vSwitch1 routable via RPN network of vSwitch2? Distributed Switches may be?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any solution to make LAN port group of vSwitch1 routable via
>   RPN network of vSwitch2? Distributed Switches may be?

No and no - no in vSwitches, the key is in their name, they're switches not routers - you need to install a router, may I suggest [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/).

Comment: I can't use a router because there is no an ability to create additional interface to get an additional IP address inside RPN network.